# MySQL and system 'root' account(s)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, root

I set RootPermitLogin to 'no' and locked system 'root' account with passwd -l. Anyway I thought that MySQL 'root' account was something "different" from the system one! The problem is that now if I try a command like (for example):

```
zcat db.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p db_name
```

I get: ERROR 1045 (28000):

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Ok I locked my system 'root' account but I previously set a DIFFERENT password for my MySQL 'root' account! What's happening here? And the strange thing is that I get this error when I try to execute these commands but applications like WordPress or SMF manage to connect to their database using the same MySQL 'root' account password..

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Like Linux, you should only use the root account if absolutely necessary. Using that rule of thumb will prevent you making mistakes that are difficult to rectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL root account is internal MySQL administrative account.

Linux root user account is something completely diffrent and its not related with MySQL.

Comment: So why do I get that error if password is properly set for MySQL 'root' account (in fact WordPress and SMF can access their databases)?

Comment: MySQL login requires 3 things: 1. valid user 2. valid password 3. valid host, thats why there is information about root@localhost (not just root). Maybe your SMF or Wordpress can connect from one host, but you cant from other host, even with valid user and password. One more thing - maybe WordPress and SMF have separate MySQL accounts and they are not using root account?

Comment: Uhm.. no, they're using the same 'root' account and are in the same host. I can't even type the password because I get that error before entering the password...

Comment: You are doing it wrong, if your command is "mysql -u root -p db_name" and db_name is not a password. Parameter "-p" is for password. For database name you have to use "-D" parameter. Command should look like this: "mysql -u root -p your_password -D your_database_name

Comment: No, server should ask the password.

Comment: Server is asking for password when you are not using -p parameter.

Comment: I tried with mysql -u root but I got
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17518/discussion-between-kamil-and-multiformeingegno)